# Reset rqt_console config

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After I accidentally dragged the top of the rqt_console, my rqt_console now only shows a blank window (just a window with a white background).  How can I reset the rqt_console configuration to restore normal behavior?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352407/reset-rqt_console-config/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could see whether removing `~/.config/ros.org/rqt_gui.ini` helps.

Be sure to make a backup of the file first. You may want to restore it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-05-20**:
Thanks that solved it!